# Relative number of firstborn

Tags: bamidbar-parsha

I have been wondering about this for a while:

In Bamidbar, 3:43, it mentions that the number of firstborn males (one month and older) was 22,273.  Now, we were just told that the number of total males (ages 20+) was just over 600,000.  This gives us a ratio of ~1:30 for firstborn:children, which seems rather low.

Now, maybe there was a disproportionate number of female firstborn, or perhaps there was some other qualification that disqualified a large percentage of firstborn from officially being "firstborn", but I haven't ever come across anything suggesting that.

Does anyone know of any source addressing this point?